# INSERT when NOT duplicate row?

Tags: mysql, insert, replace, upsert

I simply want to replace (update) `DATE`, `PRICE` and `OLDPRICE` when a price is different than the PRICE in my table where `MODEL` is unique.

Sample Row Table Data:

```
DATE        |   MAKE   |   MODEL   |   PRICE   |   OLDPRICE
2012-04-15  | Advance  | DTA-100-X |   400     |   390
```

There must be a dozen ways to do this but I'm looking for the best solution to use in a MySQL query.

Should I be using:

1. `INSERT INTO..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
2. `REPLACE INTO..`
3. `UPDATE...WHERE PRICE != XXX`

Essential syntax would be to `UPDATE` if the `MODEL` is the same but the `PRICE` is different; `OLDPRICE` becomes `PRICE` on `UPDATE`

****UPDATE****

This REPLACES whether price changed or not.  I only want updates/replaces if price changed ie, this should NOT update anything given above example, however it does because date is different:

```
REPLACE INTO MyTable (DATE, MAKE, MODEL, PRICE, OLDPRICE) VALUES ('2012-10-02', 'Advance', 'DTA-100-X', '400', '390')
```

Comment: The useful term is "upsert" (a combination between UPdate and inSERT).

Comment: I've used method number 1 for several years, works fine. Both 1 and 2 will also insert new data to the table if there's no matching key already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a [`REPLACE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) specifically for this purpose.

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html

Comment: With the caveat that the row is in fact *deleted* first.  If you are ok with that momentary discontinuity in your data this is pretty easy to do.

Comment: Ok this sounds like it is what I need as long as it does not insert or update all data unless the `PRICE` is different for that row

Comment: Replace always does a delete and insert, even if the new values are exactly the same as the old values.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I believe that if you're using a table engine that supports transactions (eg. Innodb), each SQL statement runs in a transaction (unless `autocommit` is off) and there is no "momentary discontinuity".

Comment: @Asaph that might be true; it would make sense that it is an implicit part of a transaction, but I wouldn't trust it unless I saw it in the reference manual.  Just something to be aware of, though.

Comment: I tried using `REPLACE` but it replaces all data regardless of unique or primaries, see updated edit

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the order of the table, use `INSERT INTO..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. `REPLACE` will **delete the old row and then add a new one**, if it finds a duplicate.

`INSERT INTO..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does, as the name suggests, inserts a new row into the table unless there's a duplicate, in which case it will update the row (instead of removing it and adding a new one) which will make the order of the table the same.

Comment: This seems like it would be faster as well compared to `REPLACE`, thoughts?

Comment: The question is a little vague, but given the info at hand I'll recommend this over replace since it's more efficient and less invasive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, you should use option 1, the upsert, aka `INSERT...ON DULICATE KEY UPDATE`.

I think you are saying you only want to update the PRICE and OLDPRICE (not DATE or MAKE) if the model already exists with a difference price. If that's the case, this should work for you:

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (DATE, MAKE, MODEL, PRICE, OLDPRICE) 
VALUES ('2012-10-02', 'Advance', 'DTA-100-X', '410', '390')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE OLDPRICE = CASE WHEN PRICE != VALUES(PRICE) THEN PRICE ELSE OLDPRICE END,
  DATE = CASE WHEN PRICE != VALUES(PRICE) THEN VALUES(DATE) ELSE DATE END,
  PRICE = VALUES(PRICE);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, i'd like to also update DATE if the price has changed as well

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I updated the sample query accordingly.